# Node.js request inside express server doesn't seem to work in parallel

Tags: node.js, express, node-request

I've a simple express server responding to one post request:
app.post('/reportFiles', getReportLink);

The server is going to make a post request on another server then save the result into a json file.
But it seems to be not working when i make multiple request. If I call 2 times my express server and the request to the other server are slow, I'll get the result of my first request but never my second (request are the same, just called 2 times).

Here is my code for the function getReportLink:

```
function getReportLink(req,res){
    var params = req.body;

    // Send 200 response -> Doing the job in background
    respond(res,200,'OK');

    var json;
    var requestName = params.requestName;
    var sessionId = params.sessionId;
    var startDate = params.startDate;
    var endDate = params.endDate;
    var customerId = params.customerId;
    var uaid = params.uaid;
    var jsonFileName = requestName+'_'+customerId+'_'+uaid+'_'+unix()+'.json';
    var platformUrl = require(current_path+path.sep+'platform').getPlatformUrl(config.environment);


    async.series([
        // Call getrequestName on spring-ws
        function(callback){
            var requestBody = {sessionId:sessionId,asynch:false,startDate:startDate,endDate:endDate,formatedForTimezone:true,timeZoneOffset:timeZoneOffset};
            var reportParams = params;
            _.each(_.keys(reportParams), function (key) {
                if(key==='reportType' && reportParams[key]<=0){
                    // We don't add it
                }else{
                    requestBody[key] = reportParams[key];
                }

            });
            logger.debug(jsonFileName);
            logger.debug(requestBody);

            request({
                uri: platformUrl+'get'+reportParams.requestName,
                method: 'POST',
                json: true,
                timeout: 600000,
                headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
                body: requestBody}, 
                function(error, response, body) {
                    if(!_.isUndefined(response)){
                        logger.debug(jsonFileName);
                        logger.debug('Response: '+ response.statusCode);
                    }
                    if (error || response.statusCode == 500) {
                        logger.debug(jsonFileName);
                        logger.error(error);
                        logger.debug('Received:'+JSON.stringify(body));
                        if(!_.isUndefined(returnUrl) && returnUrl){
                            return respond(res,500, 'Error when getting ressource');
                        } else {
                            return logger.error('Error when getting ressource');
                        }
                    } else {
                        json = body;
                        if( _.isUndefined(json) || _.isNull(json)){
                            logger.debug(jsonFileName);
                            logger.debug('Received:'+JSON.stringify(json));
                            if(!_.isUndefined(returnUrl) && returnUrl){
                                return respond(res,500, 'Error when getting ressource - not a json object');
                            } else {
                                return logger.error('Error when getting ressource - not a json object');
                            }
                        } else {
                            logger.debug(jsonFileName+' : '+' OK go to next');
                            callback(null, 'getReportName');
                        }

                    }
                });
        },
        // Save Json on filesystem
        function(callback){
            logger.debug(jsonFileName+' : '+' Saving on disk');
            if(_.isUndefined(json)){
                logger.error('Json is undefined...');
            }
            fs.writeFile(jsonFileName, JSON.stringify(json), 'utf8', function (err) {
                if (err) return logger.error(params);
                callback(null, 'writeJson');
            });
        }
    ]);
}
```

Comment: but you are using `async.series`, you should use `async.parallel` for this stuff or there is something that I do not understand.

Comment: my fonction getReportLink is what's executed for each request to my express server and in the function, i'm doing async with one request and one write to the disk.

Comment: My problem is that when I call this method 2 times (2 request to my server). The first one is going well but the second one not...

Answer (score 1):

Solved this using [node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch).
Code instead of request now looks like this:

```
fetch(uri, { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(requestBody), timeout: 600000, headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'} })
                .then(function(response) {
                    logger.debug('Response: '+ response.status + ' ok?'+response.ok);


                    if (!response.ok) {
                        logger.debug('Received: '+response.statusText);
                        return respond(res,500, 'Error when getting ressource. Status='+response.status);
                    } else{
                        json = response.json();
                        if( _.isUndefined(json) || _.isNull(json)){ 
                            return respond(res,500, 'Error when getting ressource');
                        } else {
                            callback(null, 'getReportName');
                        }
                    }
                });
```